To get sum of fields in a payroll table and save in RDLC report
I am working on a payroll program.
I want to get the Tax Report where I can sum the fields BASIC, RELIEFS, PAYE, etc. for each staff and save the result in another table from which I can view or print it with the RDLC report.
There are two tables; STAFFDATA and PAYROLL. There are 225 records in STAFFDATA and 20 records in PAYROLL because I took a sample of 10 people and computed their payroll.
I then select a staffid field in the STAFFDATA and go to payroll to sort the records and sum the needed fields, then save the resulting data in another temporary file PAYTEMP.
This is what I did:
Try
        Dim MonthlyBasic As Double
        Dim MonthlyBasic1 As Double
        Dim Rent As Double
        Dim Rent1 As Double
        Dim Transport As Double
        Dim Transport1 As Double
        Dim OtherA As Double
        Dim OtherA1 As Double
        Dim Reliefs As Double
        Dim Reliefs1 As Double
        Dim PAYE As Double
        Dim PAYE1 As Double

        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
        Dim b As String = "Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source= C:\ECTSPAYROLL\ECTSPAY.accdb " 'this location can be edited in the settings or the app.config file

        Dim a As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(b)

        conDb.Open()
        sql = "Delete * from PAYTEMP"
        cmd.Connection = conDb
        cmd.CommandText = sql

        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

        Dim mySelect1 As String = ("SELECT * FROM STAFFDATA")

        Dim adapter1 As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(mySelect1, conDb)
        Dim ds1 As DataSet = New DataSet
        adapter1.Fill(ds1, "STAFFDATA")

        For Index1 = 0 To ds1.Tables("STAFFDATA").Rows.Count - 1
            StaffID = ds1.Tables("STAFFDATA").Rows(Index1).Item("STAFFID")
            Surname = ds1.Tables("STAFFDATA").Rows(Index1).Item("SURNAME")
            OtherNames = ds1.Tables("STAFFDATA").Rows(Index1).Item("OTHERNAMES")

            MonthlyBasic1 = 0
            Rent1 = 0
            Transport1 = 0
            OtherA1 = 0
            Reliefs1 = 0
            PAYE1 = 0

            a.Open()

            Dim mySelect As String = ("SELECT * FROM PAYROLL WHERE (SALARYYEAR='" & txtYear.Text & "')")

            Dim adapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(mySelect, b)
            adapter.Fill(ds, "PAYROLL")

            For index = 0 To ds.Tables("PAYROLL").Rows.Count - 1
                If ds.Tables("PAYROLL").Rows(index).Item("STAFFID").ToString.ToLower.Equals(StaffID.ToLower) Then 'And ds.Tables("PAYROLL").Rows(index).Item("SALARYYEAR").ToString.ToLower.Equals(txtYear.Text.ToLower) Then
                    'If ds.Tables("PAYROLL").Rows(index).Item("SURNAME").ToString.ToLower.Equals(Surname.ToLower) And ds.Tables("PAYROLL").Rows(index).Item("OTHERNAMES").ToString.ToLower.Equals(OtherNames.ToLower) Then
                    Surname = ds.Tables("PAYROLL").Rows(index).Item("SURNAME")
                    OtherNames = ds.Tables("PAYROLL").Rows(index).Item("OTHERNAMES")
                    Department = ds.Tables("PAYROLL").Rows(index).Item("DEPARTMENT")
                    TINNo = ds.Tables("PAYROLL").Rows(index).Item("TINNO")
                    MonthlyBasic = ds.Tables("PAYROLL").Rows(index).Item("BASICPM")
                    Rent = ds.Tables("PAYROLL").Rows(index).Item("RENT")
                    Transport = ds.Tables("PAYROLL").Rows(index).Item("TRANSPORT")
                    OtherA = ds.Tables("PAYROLL").Rows(index).Item("OTHERA")
                    Reliefs = ds.Tables("PAYROLL").Rows(index).Item("RELIEFS")
                    PAYE = ds.Tables("PAYROLL").Rows(index).Item("PAYE")

                    MonthlyBasic1 = MonthlyBasic1 + MonthlyBasic
                    RENT1 = RENT1 + Rent
                    Transport1 = Transport1 + Transport
                    OtherA1 = OtherA1 + OtherA
                    Reliefs1 = Reliefs
                    PAYE1 = PAYE1 + PAYE

                End If
            Next
            StaffName = Surname & ", " & OtherNames
            DeductionHeading = "ANNUAL TAX RETURNS FOR YEAR " & txtYear.Text

            sql1 = "INSERT INTO PAYTEMP (HEADINGS,STAFFID,SURNAME,DEPARTMENT,TINNO,BASICPM,RENT,TRANSPORT,OTHERA,RELIEFS,PAYE) values ('" & DeductionHeading & "','" & StaffID & "','" & StaffName & "','" & Department & "','" & TINNo & "','" & MonthlyBasic1 & "','" & Rent1 & "','" & Transport1 & "','" & OtherA1 & "','" & Reliefs1 & "','" & PAYE1 & "');"

            cmd1.Connection = a
            cmd1.CommandText = sql1

            j = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery

            StaffName = ""

            a.Close()

        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    Finally
        conDb.Close()
    End Try

When I run this, this is what I get in the PAYTEMP file which I intend to use for the RDLC Report.
I could not copy and paste it from Excel.
Only the first record is correct.
The other records keep increasing, repeating some records many times until it gets to 225 records instead of 10 which I expect.
I don't know where I got it wrong.

First, please set Option Strict On. Then when you have corrected all the problems that Visual Studio shows you, [edit] your question to show the new, corrected code.

But before that, if the images show data of real people then you need to delete those images right now. And consult your company's data protection people on what needs to be done about exposing that personally identifiable information (PII), and how those people need to be compensated.

Further: just because the images don't show in the current revision doesn't mean they are gone. That data is still visible via the revision history. This is a big deal. The good news is that TINNO field is duplicated, so its probably a business unit tax number instead of an employee tax number. But salary numbers and employee IDs are still out there.

Also: NEVER use string concatenation to put data into SQL command strings. Never. Don't do it. Instead, learn about parameterized queries.

My Access SQL is a little rusty (I work in SQL Server more often), but you want something closer to the below code, that does most of the work on the database in the first place, groups by the person data to sum up the totals, and uses query parameters to include the necessary information from the client:
Dim cnString As String = "Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source= C:\ECTSPAYROLL\ECTSPAY.accdb " 'this location can be edited in the settings or the app.config file

Dim heading As String = "ANNUAL TAX RETURNS FOR YEAR " & txtYear.Text
Dim sql As String = "
DELETE FROM PAYTEMP;
INSERT INTO PAYTEMP 
    (HEADINGS, STAFFID, SURNAME, DEPARTMENT, TINNO, BASICPM, RENT, 
     TRANSPORT, OTHERA, RELIEFS, PAYE)
SELECT ?, StaffData.StaffID, StaffData.SurName + ', ' + StaffData.OtherNames, 
    Payroll.Department, Payroll.TINNO,
    SUM(Payroll.BasicPM), SUM(Payroll.Rent), SUM(Payroll.Transport),
    SUM(Payroll.OtherA), SUM(Payroll.Reliefs), SUM(Payroll.PayE)
FROM StaffData
INNER JOIN Payroll ON (StaffData.StaffID = Payroll.StaffID)
WHERE ( Payroll.SalaryYear = ? )
GROUP BY StaffData.StaffID, StaffData.SurName, StaffData.OtherNames, Payroll.Department"

' Best to keep try/catch blocks as short as possible, and you don't need one just to declare a few string variables.
Try
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection(cnString)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)

    ' For OleDb, the "name" argument doesn't matter. Instead, it matches up based on the order of the ? placeholder in the SQL with the order the parameter is added
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", heading)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtYear.Text)

    con.Open() ' Good to wait to last possible moment before opening the connection
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    con.Dispose() ' Dispose also ensures connection is closed
    cmd.Dispose()
End Try

Once you get this far, where we see this entire thing can be expressed as a single SQL statement, perhaps we can further eliminate the PayTemp table completely, where you just run the SELECT query to get the results. But for payroll, you may still want a record of what was done, where this instead adds BatchNumber and Timestamp columns to the table, to preserve a record of what was done and when.
